# RegEx phone number followed by some unknown text then a word

Tags: regex, phone-number, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to write a regex that matches phone numbers followed by any number of letters, digits, possible symbols until I find the next instance of the word Subject.

I've almost found a solution but it includes matches numbers before it because the regex is too ambiguous. Well, that and the fact I suck at regex.

In the example, it matches the first and second number up until the word Subject, I only want it to get the number closest to the word "Subject" while the number still being before the word. There may be more than one instance of this that I need to detect within a document. The text may spread multiple lines. The only part I need captured is the phone number, the rest will be a none capture group.

Can I even do this in RegEx alone? Or do i have to start stripping stuff out in another language? This will be going into a PHP script if that matters.

**Example**

RegEx

```
([0-9]{3}\-[0-9]{3}\-[0-9]{4})(?:\w|\s|\-|\')+\bSubject\b
```

Section:

```
123-456-7890 - ABC WHAT
MERICA RULES
987-654-3210 - ABC WHAT WORDS MORE WORDS 123456789123
LOREM IPSOM WHO CARES - Subject
```

Answer (score 0):

You can match all with the `g`lobal modifier, and then take the last match?

```
/(\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4})(?=.*\bSubject\b)/sg
```

`s`ingle line makes `.` match newlines as well.

And in PHP:

```
<?php
$input = '123-456-7890 - ABC WHAT
MERICA RULES
987-654-3210 - ABC WHAT WORDS MORE WORDS 123456789123
LOREM IPSOM WHO CARES - Subject
ANOTHER NOT MATCHES BECAUSE AFTER subject 111-111-1111';

preg_match_all('/(\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4})(?=.*\bSubject\b)/s', $input, $matches);

echo array_pop($matches[1]); // 987-654-3210
?>
```

[Try it online](https://regex101.com/r/gV1aO3/2)

Comment: This doesn't work, if you copy and paste your input twice in the regex tester, the 111-111-1111 is matched.

https://regex101.com/r/gV1aO3/3

Comment: @user2078965 That's because you have a `Subject` later in the text.

Comment: That's one of my issues, it is going to occur multiple times within a document and I need to be able to detect that.

Comment: @user2078965 I don't think it's possible with one regex since variable length lookbehinds are not supported in PCRE. If you can find a pattern you could split on that and then run the above regex on each chunk.

Comment: Ok thanks! I was worried that it would be a bit too complex to do with just a RegEx. Thanks for all your help andlrc, I really appreciate it!

Comment: @user2078965 I'm happy I could, if not answer your question, at least give you some information and ideas for how you can solve it!

Comment: @user2078965 The main problem is that you would need to ensure there is no Subject before the matched phone number, sounds like a job for negative lookbehinds, but since variable length are not supported in PCRE it would not be possible.

Comment: My solution is the just explode() input text by the word subject then just fine in last occurrence of a phone number in each subset.